# Can i prevent my system reading any USB files?

Tags: security, usb-drive

I have some computers around me. I don't want any one to insert any USB. Am afraid someone has malware in the USB when inserting in one computer it will infect the others, because they are connected each other. That happened last time when I brought some experts to fix them.

**I want to prevent this and make the system doesn't allow any files of working or even reading files from USB.**

Is that possible?

Comment: well first of all , affecting linux is not simple . secondly do you want to disable usb of your computer , so that no one can connect anything to USB

Comment: use that is my goal? to prevent inserting any malwares by USB

Comment: @user28179 , are you still looking for alternative solution of this?

Answer (score 1):

Affecting linux is not simple and chances of being affected is really negligible but still if you want then..

You can do it by disabling USB , for disabling use -

```
sudo echo "blacklist usb-storage" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

it will create a line as blacklist usb-storage , to enable it again -

```
sudo gedit etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and search for the line `"blacklist usb-storage"` remove it. Be sure what you are going todo before doing anything .

hope it solves your need..

Comment: if i did that right, even if the USB has malware it will not affect the system?

Comment: see malware can make issues with windows , but its just not that easy in linux, thats why am suggesting you to let it be as it is, because in future you will definitely need usb.But still if you dont want to allow anyone else exploring usb sticks or other stuffs then disable it.

Comment: am sure i don't want it also in the future and want to disable it but the question is if i disabled it and the usb has malware will it affect the system or not?

Comment: no it will not.. dont worry .

Answer (score 1):

Since you [will be prompted](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/autorun#Example) before autorun, I would be less concerned with malware being distributed by a mass-storage device.

[image]

What I would be more concerned with is a malicious USB device that emulates a keyboard or other user input device. To reduce the risk of this type of "malware" attack, you could use UDEV rules to disable all USB devices by default and white list specific devices that you regularly use, like your keyboard or mouse.

Sutekh illustrates how to create and enact UDEV rules in Ubuntu [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221). You basically create a new file under /etc/udev/rules.d/ for your new rules, then restart the udev daemon.

Stéphane gives [a nice example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment#answer-63237) of a disable all followed by whitelisting UDEV ruleset. But I would recommend being more specific in your whitelist rule than relying just on idVendor to identify your device.

There are [over a dozen UDEV attributes](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#3.2_Locking_down_Linux_using_UDEV) to a device that you can use in combination to identify your specific hardware. For instance you can even differentiate between your Dell keyboard and a different Dell keyboard by looking at the bMaxPower and and idProduct attributes.

While it is unlikely that the malicious device will go through a list of keyboard manufacturers to emulate, it is even less likely that they will go through specific product releases from that manufacturer, and specify detailed attributes like bMaxPower.

There is no perfectly secure system, and there are always additional steps in security that you can take. The goal of security is to make it not worthwhile for the attacker to expend the effort to attain their goal. Therefore the relative value of compromising your system, to both you and potential attackers should define the defenses that you put in place.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the USB automount in gconf should remedy this.

1. Open Gconf by opening your dash then typing "gconf"
2. Then navigate to / > apps > nautilus > preferences
3. Uncheck the media_automount value as seen below[image: screenshot of Gconf Nautilus Config]
4. Then close Gconf and it you should be fine :)

Doing so will disable the ability for any program on a removable device to automatically execute, although unlikely on Linux it could still be a problem.

If you are dual booting or have any computers running Windows make sure you turn off USB autorun for those machines as well.

source: http://www.usbduplicatornow.com/disable-autorun-autoplay.html

Comment: it will only stop auto mount of usb drive and anyone can easily mount it trough command line .

Comment: Anyone can do anything if they have extended access to the computer. My answer simple eliminates the ability for a person to insert an USB which contains a pre-packaged program that will run immediately upon USB insertion.
If the person has access to the computer they can pretty much do anything.

Comment: Agreed!! even its simple . I am trying it now..